# Assigning value to only certain object variables in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I have a complicated RPG character model I'm working on as a side project. For this RPG, there are 6 basic 'ability scores' (strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma) that each character has. I'm specifically focusing on the tests for setting them to 0, which should be invalid (character death, etc). Here is what I have in rspec:

```
describe "when ability scores are 0" do
  ability_scores = %w(strength dexterity constitution
                      intelligence wisdom charisma)
  ability_scores.each do |ability_score|
    @character.ability_score = 0
    expect(@character).to be_invalid
  end
end
```

I have a factory at the beginning of the file creating a perfectly valid character and set `subject { @character }`

I would *think* that it would see the `ability_score` and think to insert its value before evaluating against the character object, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Switching out `@character.send(:"#{ability_score}=", 0)` for `@character.ability_score = 0` results in a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'strength=' for nil:NilClass`

However, separate `describe` blocks work fine:

```
describe "when strength is 0" do
  before { @character.strength = 0 }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

but having 6 of these is a cluttering mess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has an issue

```
character.ability_score = 0
```

This line sends calls a method called `:ability_score=` on the `character` object, but I think what you want is to set the variables referred to by the array of strings over which you are iterating.

Luckily, you can call arbitrary methods on your objects using `send`. You can turn your strings into symbols that refer to your setter methods, and then send that as a message to `character`:

```
character.send(:"#{ability_score}=", 0)
```

(Note: you don't actually need to send a symbol; you can leave it as a string if you wish).
In effect, this is exactly like calling `character.strength = 0`, etc.

**EDIT**

Change the contents of your `describe` block to define tests:

```
describe "when ability scores are 0" do
  %w(strength dexterity constitution intelligence wisdom charisma).each do |ability_score|
    it "is invalid when #{ability_score} is 0" do
      @character.send("#{ability_score}=", 0)
      expect(@character).to be_invalid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: results in `NoMethodError: undefined method 'strength=' for nil:NilClass`, also changed reference to character to an instance variable. Assignment works in a separate describe block. I'm adding both to my original quesiton.

Comment: Where are you initializing `@character`?

Comment: It looks like your expectations are just happening in the context of a `describe` block, and not in an actual test (`it { ... }` or `specify { .. }`). The instance variable wouldn't be accessible in that scope (see edited answer).

Comment: That makes sense. Given the `it/specify` problem, I've rewritten the code to assign during the test instead. That fixed the problem. The `@character` is being initialized in the root describe block using let and being built by a factory. Thanks @zach-kemp!